Late 80's/90's show with puppets about a young bird in a forest
I had a bunch of videos when i was a child of this so it would have been 80's or 90's. I can only really remember one episode. 
I think the main character was a young bird, an owl I think. it was set in a Forest or woodland. In this episode He was carried off by a massive black bird that to its nest either to eat or to feed his young. the young bird ended up escaping. I think with help. they all talked and they were all puppets, or at least stop motion.

it was orm and cheep. thank you for your time!

If you found your answer, you can always put it up.

As per the querent's answer in the comments, this is Orm and Cheep

Orm and Cheep is a 1980s British children's television series that was aimed at the younger viewers of CITV. It used puppets as the main characters (Orm being a worm and Cheep being a bird) and was narrated by Richard Briers. The show was created by Tony Martin, the puppets created by Mary Edwards. There were a total of 26 episodes, which spanned between the years of 1983–1985, each episode consisting of eleven minutes.

....

Cheep was an infant bird who fell from his nest, prior to learning to fly (the theme tune, "If only Cheep could fly", ensured that Cheep's difficulties in learning to fly became a recurring joke throughout the series). He befriends Orm, a worm who inhabits a subterranean home. Their acquaintances include Snail and Mouse, all friends and foes have a single-word, noun name. Their notable foes include Rat and Crow, who often scheme to consume the pair.





Just so that we have an answer on record. Sam Spiller, if and when you return, feel free to co-opt the entirety of its contents.
